# Control that filters data in excel

Tags: excel-2007

I am working with some data in Excel. I was wondering if it is at all possible to setup a filter that will interact with a drop-down menu.

For example:
I have a list of all the cities in Illinois and they are organized by which county they are in. Is there a way to add a drop down menu control with a list of counties in it (which I can do) and a filter that will show only one county (which I can do) and then have them interact so that the filter only shows the county selected in the drop down menu (which I have no idea how to do).

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the Filter option from the Data ribbon it will add filter buttons to the header cells of your sheet.  You can then pull down the filter button on the County column and pick only the county you're interested in.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the quick response. But I'm looking for a way to make a drop down menu where I can select a county, and that menu will tell the filter which county to sort for. Any idea on how I can do that?